# Getting all point on the line segment - Solved

Tags: java

I found a practice java class and I am trying to get all points on the line segment such that for every point x and y are both integers but I am having trouble of implementing it. I am just looking for a formula I can use to solve the problem. or explain me how it get point (3,2). Thanks

```
    /**
 * 
 * @return an array containing all points on the line segment such that for every point in the array,
 * both x and y are integers
 * For example, if there is a line from (1,1) to (5,3), the only other point for which both x and y are 
 * integers is (3,2). Thus the method should return the array containing (1,1), (3,2) and (5,3)
 * The order of points in the array returned should be from the point with lower x 
 * (use Point a as the starting point in case a.x == b.x).
 * 
 * Hence if a = (5,1) and b=(1,3), the method returns an array such that 
 * first item is (1,3), second is (3,2) and third is (5,1)
 */

public Point[] getPointsOnCrosshair() {
    Point[] points = new Point[20];
    int counter = 0;
    //getting slope of the line
    double rise = this.b.y - this.a.y;
    double run = this.b.x - this.a.x;
    double m = rise/run;
    System.out.println(m);
    //getting value of c -> y = mx + c 
    double c = a.y - (m * a.x);

    int start = 0;
    int end = 0;
    if (b.x >= a.x){
        start = a.x;
        end = b.x;
    }
    else{
        start = b.x;
        end = a.x;          
    }
    // slope intercept y - y1 = m (x-x1)
    // y = (m (x-x1)) + y1
    double y = 0;
    for (int a = start; a <= end; a++){
        y = (m * a) + c;
        if (y == (int) y){
            points[counter] = new Point(a, (int) y);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    return points;
}
```

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/497327/142097 etc, but searching around will provide additional options. Note this is more of a math question.

Comment: `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(y))` will crash and burn, when if the `y` value is a pure integer, e.g. **NumberFormatException: For input string: "1.0"**

Comment: updated. @Andreas ..

Comment: @DaveNewton . I have checked the link. thank you .

Comment: code updated with the solution I found. any suggestion for improvement?

Comment: You shouldn't replace the code in the question with the solution, or add `Solved` in the title. Instead, self-answer the question by creating an answer with the solution. You then **Accept** that answer, to show others that the question has been solved. If others find the answer useful, you might even get a [**Self-Learner**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/14/self-learner) badge by doing that. --- You should also up-vote any answer you found useful.

Answer (score 0):

First, determine if the line is mostly horizontal or mostly vertical.

```
▉ ▉            ▉
    ▉ ▉        ▉
        ▉ ▉      ▉
                  ▉
                    ▉
                    ▉
```

If it is mostly horizontal, you iterate `x` from `a.x` to `b.x` and calculate `y`.

If it is mostly vertical, you iterate `y` from `a.y` to `b.y` and calculate `x`.

I'll leave it to you to build the right formula, or to go find it on the web, i.e. do some *research*.

Comment: @Geeeee No, you don't do the vertical logic, and you shouldn't be using `double` math at all, and the size of the point array is all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force solution is really simple:

```java
int p1x = 1;
int p1y = 1;
int p2x = 5;
int p2y = 3;

int xdiff = p2x - p1x;
int ydiff = p2y - p1y;

for (int x = p1x + 1; x < p2x; ++x) {
    float y = ((float) x - p1x) / xdiff * ydiff + p1y;
    if (((int) y) == y) { // check if xx.0
        System.out.print(x);
        System.out.print(", ");
        System.out.println((int)y);
    }
}
```

But I'm sure there's a more elegant way, maybe using prime factorization